# How to change ItemWriter target filename in a spring-batch job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a `MultiResourceItemReader` that loads multiple `csv` files from a folder.

For each file I'd like to change the filename that an `ItemWriter` is generating. But: how?

```
@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<String> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<String> delegate = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

    MultiResourceItemReader<String> r = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    r.setResources(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("*.csv"));
    r.setDelegate(delegate);
    return r;
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<String> writer() {
    FlatFileItemWriter<String> w = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
    w.setResource(new FileSystemResource("dynamicfile.txt); //how dynamically, eg depending on the input filename?
    w.setLineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>());
    return w;
}
```

Is it possible at all? And if not, how could I then write the data to different files using `ItemWriter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the file name for a `FlatFileItemReader` instance because of the details around buffering, etc.  However, there are two approaches you can use to accomplish the same thing.

**`ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`**
Using the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`, you'd create one `FlatFileItemWriter` for each file you want to write to.  Then you'd create a `Classifier` implementation that chooses the reader based on the input item.  The `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` would use the `Classifier` you provide to choose which writer to use for each item.

You can read more about the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html

**Partitioning by resource**
If the following conditions are met, you could use partitioning to handle the same thing:

1. Multiple input files
2. Multiple output files
3. The input files can be processed in parallel

In this case, implementing a `Partitioner` that is similar to the `MultiResourcePartitioner`, you can process each file independently (same logic as the `MultiResourcePartitioner`, just with the added attribute of the output file information as well).  With a step scoped reader and writer, the input source and output destination could be configured dynamically.

You can read more about partitioning here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Both sounds promising, so which one would you advise to use for the following use case: about 20.000 zipped csv files, each of only several mb. every file should be read, transformed (=strip data) and finally written to an output file. So at the end I should have 20.000 csv files in output dir. Order of processing does not matter in any case. The whole process should run several times a day. Is the `MultiResourcePartitioner` best for this situation?

Comment: If you can use partitioning for this use case, I would.  It's probably an easier thing to implement and allows for further scaling if needed.

Comment: I tried partitioner and it works in general. But: the written filename should contain a value that is first known inside the processor (a value from within first line of the file). How can I pass this value eg as `stepExecutionContext` to the `FlatFileItemWriter` so that the name is taken into account?

Comment: That won't work.  The `FlatFileItemWriter` is open at the start of the step.  The only other option you'd have is to use a listener to figure it out first.

Comment: Ok, as a workaround I'm renaming the `resource` file within `itemwriter.close()`. That works too. Strange thing is that `close()` is called twice on my my `@StepScope`d writer...?